# WordPress query for a single value inside a multiple values column, with serialized string format

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm been looking for a while how to achieve this, no luck so far, what I have is a meta value which has multiple values in it and is serialized string format, and looks like this:

```
a:2:{s:15:"s2member_level2";b:1;s:26:"access_s2member_ccap_one_m";b:1;}
```

And this meta value varies from user to user, what i need to do is, get all of the values the includes the `s2member_level2` in it, this is what i came out with:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value = 's2member_level2' ");
```

I really need to get it directly from the data base, so can not use wordpress functions

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just do a `meta_value LIKE '%s2member_level2%'` to obtain all rows where the serialized string contains this value.

Comment: Thanks TheCandyMan for answering, already tryied that, for some reason does not work, if i hardcode the `$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value = 'a:2:{s:15:\"s2member_level2\";b:1;s:26:\"access_s2member_ccap_one_m\";b:1;}' ");` that returns the users the meet criteria, but if i use `$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value = LIKE '%s2member_level2%' ");` it just return 0, still trying to figurate this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround that you can try which basically does the filtering outside the query.

1) Get all the the pairs user_id,meta_value from wp_usermeta

```
 select user_id,meta_value from wp_usermeta where meta_key="wp_capabilities
```

2) Inside the result array you can search for "s2member_level2" meta_values and get the corresponding user_id.

3) Once you have all the user_ids that you need, you can just retrieve each "wp_capabilities" value and unserialize it.

```
 select meta_value from wp_usermeta where meta_key="wp_capabilities" AND user_id="..."
```

Take a look at the unserialize function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php